# In amazon linux 2 how to set defalut python to python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2

In Amazon linx 2 currently command `python` points to python2. How do I set so that for all profile and command uses python3 when python command is called?
Currently i am editing `~/.bashrc` and adding `alias python=python3`. But I what it to be default across the system.

Comment: Making that a *system-wide* default is a bad idea. You're too likely to break something important you've never heard of.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do it.
Python 2 is still used by the YUM (the package manager of Amazon Linux). Making Python 3 default will stop you from installing software updates. Python2 is also used in other places of this linux distribution.